# Multiple Case When slows down query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query with multiple case-whens for each respective 'AttributeId' column from another table which gets aggregated. Adding these statements increases the time-complexity significantly. I would appreciate any suggestions for improving the performance as I am not so well-versed with TSQL.

The query:

```sql
SELECT t1.ServiceWaittime,
       t1.Starttime,
       t1.Endtime,
       t1.prevEndTime,
       CONVERT(float, t1.Starttime - t1.prevEndTime) / 24.0 / 60.0 AS continuityDuration,
       t1.Duration,
       t1.MainCpseId,
       t1.Yield,
       t1.Scrap,
       t1.MachineYield,
       ISNULL((t1.MachineYield / NULLIF(t1.Duration, 0)), 0) AS Geschwindigkeit,
       t1.Te,
       t1.Tr,
       t1.CalendarWeek,
       t1.InterruptionTriggerAttributeId,
       t1.ReasonId,
       t1.InterruptionName,
       t1.ReasonName,
       CASE
            WHEN 1 = 1 THEN ISNULL((SELECT AVG(Value)
                                    FROM CpseEventLogger
                                    WHERE AttributeId = 4
                                      AND MainCpseId = 12
                                      AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime),
                                   0)
       END AS Sys_Speed_Value, --statement1
       CASE
            WHEN 1 = 1 THEN ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM CpseEventLogger
                                    WHERE AttributeId = 103
                                      AND MainCpseId = 12
                                      AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime),
                                   0)
       END AS attr_103, --statement2
       CASE
            WHEN 1 = 1 THEN ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM CpseEventLogger
                                    WHERE AttributeId = 292
                                      AND MainCpseId = 12
                                      AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime),
                                   0)
       END AS attr_292, --statement3
       CASE
            WHEN 1 = 1 THEN ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM CpseEventLogger
                                    WHERE AttributeId = 293
                                      AND MainCpseId = 12
                                      AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime),
                                   0)
       END AS attr_293, --statement4
       CASE
            WHEN 1 = 1 THEN ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM CpseEventLogger
                                    WHERE AttributeId = 294
                                      AND MainCpseId = 12
                                      AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime),
                                   0)
       END AS attr_294, --statement5
       CASE
            WHEN 1 = 1 THEN ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM CpseEventLogger
                                    WHERE AttributeId = 8159
                                      AND MainCpseId = 12
                                      AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime),
                                   0)
       END AS attr_8159, --statement6
       CASE
            WHEN 1 = 1 THEN ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM CpseEventLogger
                                    WHERE AttributeId = 8175
                                      AND MainCpseId = 12
                                      AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime),
                                   0)
       END AS attr_8175, --statement7
       CASE
            WHEN 1 = 1 THEN ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM CpseEventLogger
                                    WHERE AttributeId = 8186
                                      AND MainCpseId = 12
                                      AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime),
                                   0)
       END AS attr_8186, --statement8
       CASE
            WHEN 1 = 1 THEN ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM CpseEventLogger
                                    WHERE AttributeId = 8208
                                      AND MainCpseId = 12
                                      AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime),
                                   0)
       END AS attr_8208, --statement9
       CASE
            WHEN 1 = 1 THEN ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM CpseEventLogger
                                    WHERE AttributeId = 8209
                                      AND MainCpseId = 12
                                      AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime),
                                   0)
       END AS attr_8209 --statement10

FROM (SELECT t1.TimeType,
             t1.ServiceWaittime,
             t1.Starttime,
             t1.Endtime,
             LAG(t1.Endtime) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.MainCpseId ORDER BY t1.Starttime ASC) AS prevEndTime,
             t1.Duration,
             t1.MainCpseId,
             t1.Yield,
             t1.Scrap,
             t1.MachineYield,
             t1.Te,
             t1.Tr,
             t1.CalendarWeek,
             t1.InterruptionTriggerAttributeId,
             t1.ReasonId,
             t2.Name AS InterruptionName,
             t3.Name AS ReasonName
      FROM CpseProcessLogger t1
           LEFT JOIN AttributeType t2 ON t1.InterruptionTriggerAttributeId = t2.Id
           LEFT JOIN Reason t3 ON t1.ReasonId = t3.Id
      WHERE 1 = 1
        AND TimeType IN ('UNT')
        AND MainCpseId = 12) t1
ORDER BY t1.Starttime ASC;
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) The above is especially confusing when `t1` references the object `CpseProcessLogger` (which doesn't have a single `t` or `1` in its name) *and* the derived table in the outer `FROM`

Comment: As for why your query is slow, you reference the object `CpseEventLogger` a total of 11 times in the above; that is very unlikely to not be expensive.

Comment: Perhaps this is a tsql pattern I'm not aware of, but why are you using case expressions here at all. The condition is always true and it feels superfluous.

Comment: @JNevill well I need separate columns for each attributeId. However, there is a better way that I am not aware of could you please provide a sample answer?

Comment: I suspect you want a pivot/conditional aggregation, @MurtazaBasu .

Comment: CASE expressions stop after the first match, so if you have `WHEN 1=1` as the first condition you will **always** get that result, and there's no point to using a CASE expression at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, which may be easier in your case, is to use `APPLY`. (`OUTER APPLY` is similar to `LEFT JOIN` and `CROSS APPLY` is similar to `INNER JOIN`).

You can use conditional aggregation within the subquery.

```sql
SELECT t1.ServiceWaittime,
       t1.Starttime,
       t1.Endtime,
       t1.prevEndTime,
       CONVERT(float, t1.Starttime - t1.prevEndTime) / 24.0 / 60.0 AS continuityDuration,
       t1.Duration,
       t1.MainCpseId,
       t1.Yield,
       t1.Scrap,
       t1.MachineYield,
       ISNULL((t1.MachineYield / NULLIF(t1.Duration, 0)), 0) AS Geschwindigkeit,
       t1.Te,
       t1.Tr,
       t1.CalendarWeek,
       t1.InterruptionTriggerAttributeId,
       t1.ReasonId,
       t1.InterruptionName,
       t1.ReasonName,
       el.Sys_Speed_Value, --statement1
       el.attr_103, --statement2
       el.attr_292, --statement3
       el.attr_293, --statement4
       el.attr_294, --statement5
       el.attr_8159, --statement6
       el.attr_8175, --statement7
       el.attr_8186, --statement8
       el.attr_8208, --statement9
       el.attr_8209 --statement10

FROM (
      SELECT t1.TimeType,
             t1.ServiceWaittime,
             t1.Starttime,
             t1.Endtime,
             LAG(t1.Endtime) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.MainCpseId ORDER BY t1.Starttime ASC) AS prevEndTime,
             t1.Duration,
             t1.MainCpseId,
             t1.Yield,
             t1.Scrap,
             t1.MachineYield,
             t1.Te,
             t1.Tr,
             t1.CalendarWeek,
             t1.InterruptionTriggerAttributeId,
             t1.ReasonId,
             t2.Name AS InterruptionName,
             t3.Name AS ReasonName
      FROM CpseProcessLogger t1
           LEFT JOIN AttributeType t2 ON t1.InterruptionTriggerAttributeId = t2.Id
           LEFT JOIN Reason t3 ON t1.ReasonId = t3.Id
      WHERE 1 = 1
        AND TimeType IN ('UNT')
        AND MainCpseId = 12
) t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      ISNULL(AVG(CASE WHEN AttributeId = 4 THEN Value END), 0) AS Sys_Speed_Value,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN AttributeId = 103 THEN 1 END) AS attr_103,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN AttributeId = 292 THEN 1 END) AS attr_292,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN AttributeId = 293 THEN 1 END) AS attr_293,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN AttributeId = 294 THEN 1 END) AS attr_294,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN AttributeId = 8159 THEN 1 END) AS attr_8159,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN AttributeId = 8175 THEN 1 END) AS attr_8175,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN AttributeId = 8186 THEN 1 END) AS attr_8186,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN AttributeId = 8208 THEN 1 END) AS attr_8208,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN AttributeId = 8209 THEN 1 END) AS attr_8209
    FROM CpseEventLogger
    WHERE MainCpseId = 12
      AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime
) el
ORDER BY t1.Starttime ASC;
```

For this query to perform well, you want the following indexes:

```
CpseEventLogger (MainCpseId, Timestamp) INCLUDE (AttributeId, Value)
CpseProcessLogger (MainCpseId, TimeType, InterruptionTriggerAttributeId) INCLUDE (
  ReasonId, .... othercolumns)
AttributeType (Id) INCLUDE (Name)
Reason (Id) INCLUDE (Name)
```

Or instead of a non-clustered index with `INCLUDE` columns, you could use a clustered index (all non-key columns are `INCLUDE`).

You may want to swap around `InterruptionTriggerAttributeId` and `ReasonId` positions in the index

Comment: Thanks for showing me to work with Cross Apply. Really powerful and exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Have also added indexing details

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess that the slow down is reading the CpseEventLogger table as @larnu suggested, you could LEFT OUTER JOIN to that table and perform the aggregation once in the main query. That would look something like:

```
SELECT t1.ServiceWaittime,
       t1.Starttime,
       t1.Endtime,
       t1.prevEndTime,
       CONVERT(float, t1.Starttime - t1.prevEndTime) / 24.0 / 60.0 AS continuityDuration,
       t1.Duration,
       t1.MainCpseId,
       t1.Yield,
       t1.Scrap,
       t1.MachineYield,
       ISNULL((t1.MachineYield / NULLIF(t1.Duration, 0)), 0) AS Geschwindigkeit,
       t1.Te,
       t1.Tr,
       t1.CalendarWeek,
       t1.InterruptionTriggerAttributeId,
       t1.ReasonId,
       t1.InterruptionName,
       t1.ReasonName,
       Avg(CASE WHEN CpseEventLogger.AttributeId = 4 THEN CpseEventLogger.Value) AS Sys_Speed_Value,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CpseEventLogger.AttributeId = 103 THENCpseEventLogger.Value) AS attr_103, --statement2
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CpseEventLogger.AttributeId = 292 THENCpseEventLogger.Value) AS attr_292, --statement3
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CpseEventLogger.AttributeId = 293 THENCpseEventLogger.Value) AS attr_293, --statement4
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CpseEventLogger.AttributeId = 294 THENCpseEventLogger.Value) AS attr_294, --statement5
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CpseEventLogger.AttributeId = 8159 THENCpseEventLogger.Value) AS attr_8159, --statement6
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CpseEventLogger.AttributeId = 8175 THENCpseEventLogger.Value) AS attr_8175, --statement7
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CpseEventLogger.AttributeId = 8186 THENCpseEventLogger.Value) AS attr_8186, --statement8
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CpseEventLogger.AttributeId = 8208 THENCpseEventLogger.Value) AS attr_8208, --statement9
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CpseEventLogger.AttributeId = 8209 THENCpseEventLogger.Value) AS attr_8209 --statement10

FROM (SELECT t1.TimeType,
             t1.ServiceWaittime,
             t1.Starttime,
             t1.Endtime,
             LAG(t1.Endtime) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.MainCpseId ORDER BY t1.Starttime ASC) AS prevEndTime,
             t1.Duration,
             t1.MainCpseId,
             t1.Yield,
             t1.Scrap,
             t1.MachineYield,
             t1.Te,
             t1.Tr,
             t1.CalendarWeek,
             t1.InterruptionTriggerAttributeId,
             t1.ReasonId,
             t2.Name AS InterruptionName,
             t3.Name AS ReasonName
      FROM CpseProcessLogger t1
           LEFT JOIN AttributeType t2 ON t1.InterruptionTriggerAttributeId = t2.Id
           LEFT JOIN Reason t3 ON t1.ReasonId = t3.Id
      WHERE 1 = 1
        AND TimeType IN ('UNT')
        AND MainCpseId = 12) t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CpseEventLogger
        ON CpseEventLogger.MainCpseId = 12
        AND CpseEvevntLogger.AttributeId IN (4,103,292,293,294,8159,8175,8186,8208,8209)
        AND CpseEventLogger.Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime
GROUP BY 
       t1.ServiceWaittime,
       t1.Starttime,
       t1.Endtime,
       t1.prevEndTime,
       continuityDuration,
       t1.Duration,
       t1.MainCpseId,
       t1.Yield,
       t1.Scrap,
       t1.MachineYield,
       Geschwindigkeit,
       t1.Te,
       t1.Tr,
       t1.CalendarWeek,
       t1.InterruptionTriggerAttributeId,
       t1.ReasonId,
       t1.InterruptionName,
       t1.ReasonName,
ORDER BY t1.Starttime ASC;
```

---

Regarding my comment on superfluous use of a case expression, your original query had the form:

```
   CASE
        WHEN 1 = 1 THEN ISNULL((SELECT AVG(Value)
                                FROM CpseEventLogger
                                WHERE AttributeId = 4
                                  AND MainCpseId = 12
                                  AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime),
                               0)
   END AS Sys_Speed_Value, --statement1
```

This is odd since we use case expression to only execute code/logic when a condition is `true`. Your condition here is `1=1` which is always true. There is only the `when` and no `else` so this is 100% identical to just:

```
   ISNULL((SELECT AVG(Value)
           FROM CpseEventLogger
           WHERE AttributeId = 4
                 AND MainCpseId = 12
                 AND Timestamp BETWEEN t1.Starttime AND t1.Endtime),
           0)
```